# Monitoring and Alerting for application traffic

Tags: monitoring, alerts, statsd

Currently I put hourly traffic (total number of input requests) of my website in a MySQL table. I keep data for the last 90 days.

I want to check every hour, lets say 6th hour, that whether the traffic has increased/decreased beyond some threshold than last 7 days or last 30 days 6th hour traffic. Basically, I see a pattern of traffic. Different hours have different values.

To generate alerts, I want to find various statistical metrics. After reading a little, I found out that `Statsd` can be used for this purpose.

Is it correct things to use for sending alerts like this? Is there any better/simpler solution for this?

I don't intend to build any dashboards.

My current data looks like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| startTime           | endTime             | component | traffic  |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | 2015-05-01 01:00:00 | rest      | 29090345 |
| 2015-05-01 01:00:00 | 2015-05-01 02:00:00 | rest      | 32224087 |
| 2015-05-01 02:00:00 | 2015-05-01 03:00:00 | rest      | 35165799 |
| 2015-05-01 03:00:00 | 2015-05-01 04:00:00 | rest      | 36903464 |
| 2015-05-01 04:00:00 | 2015-05-01 05:00:00 | rest      | 40394130 |
| 2015-05-01 05:00:00 | 2015-05-01 06:00:00 | rest      | 44874862 |
| 2015-05-01 06:00:00 | 2015-05-01 07:00:00 | rest      | 49988600 |
| 2015-05-01 07:00:00 | 2015-05-01 08:00:00 | rest      | 52240544 |
| 2015-05-01 08:00:00 | 2015-05-01 09:00:00 | rest      | 54517705 |
| 2015-05-01 09:00:00 | 2015-05-01 10:00:00 | rest      | 55277967 |
| 2015-05-01 10:00:00 | 2015-05-01 11:00:00 | rest      | 55285309 |
| 2015-05-01 11:00:00 | 2015-05-01 12:00:00 | rest      | 55572614 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.com/) might be interesting for you.
InfluxDB is a time-series database.

You could push your data either directly to InfluxDB via

- statsd
- collectd binary interface
- graphite protocol
- REST API

You can query InfluxDB via REST-API and there don't need a graphical interface. But [Grafana](http://grafana.org/) works nice with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following SQL script to compare the traffic.

```sql
set @threshold = 50;  /*threshold for comparing the traffic*/
set @limit = 30  /*how many days to consider while generating avg value*/

/*calculate the time range, comparison is done for the last hour*/
set @end_time = current_timestamp();  
set @end_time = timestamp(date(@end_time), maketime(hour(@end_time), 0, 0));
set @start_time = date_sub(@end_time, interval 1 hour);

/*find out the traffic for the last hour*/
select traffic
        from test.traffic_stats
        where startTime >= @start_time
            and endTime <= @end_time
    into @curr_traffic;

/*now find out the avg traffic for the past @limit days*/
select ifnull(avg(traffic), 0)
        from test.traffic_stats
        where startTime < @start_time
            and startTime >= date_sub(@start_time, interval @limit day)
            and time(startTime) >= time(@start_time)
            and time(endTime) <= time(@end_time)
    into @avg_traffic;

/*generate the report*/
select concat(
        'Current traffic '
        @curr_traffic,
        ' is '
        if(@curr_traffic > @avg_traffic + @threshold,
            'more',
            if(@curr_traffic < @avg_traffic - @threshold,
                'less',
                'same'
            )
        ), 
        ' compared to the avg traffic ', 
        @avg_traffic
    ) as result;
```

The script will generate the report based on avg traffic for the last 30 days by querying `test.traffic_stats` table. Please modify the script to match your requirement. Now save this SQL script as `report.sql` and you can use `Cron` to run it at specific intervals using mysql command line as given below.

```
mysql -hhost -uuser -ppassword -s <report.sql | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will extract the result and print to stdout. Now you can use GNU Mailutils to send out the alert to your email address.

```
mail -s "$(mysql -hhost -uuser -ppassword -s <report.sql | awk '{print $1}')" you@example.com
```